# Organize Array values on most common attribute

Tags: php, arrays, merge, organized

Hope someone can help me out here.

Imagine the following array:

```
Array
(
    [blue__##__m__##__10] => 13
    [blue__##__m__##__20] => 13
    [blue__##__m__##__30] => 13
    [blue__##__xl__##__10] => 18
    [blue__##__xl__##__20] => 18
    [blue__##__xl__##__30] => 18
    [blue__##__xs__##__10] => 12
    [blue__##__xs__##__20] => 12
    [blue__##__xs__##__30] => 12
    [green__##__m__##__10] => 17
    [green__##__m__##__20] => 17
    [green__##__m__##__30] => 17
    [green__##__xl__##__10] => 15
    [green__##__xl__##__20] => 15
    [green__##__xl__##__30] => 15
    [green__##__xs__##__10] => 11
    [green__##__xs__##__20] => 11
    [green__##__xs__##__30] => 11
    [red__##__m__##__10] => 16
    [red__##__m__##__20] => 16
    [red__##__m__##__30] => 16
    [red__##__xl__##__10] => 10
    [red__##__xl__##__20] => 10
    [red__##__xl__##__30] => 10
    [red__##__xs__##__10] => 21
    [red__##__xs__##__20] => 21
    [red__##__xs__##__30] => 21
)
```

I want to organize it on the most common attribute (the **##** is from a implode* the rest is attributes) removing the less uncommon.

The result should be:

```
Array
(
    [blue] => array[13,18,12]
    [green] => array[17,15,11]
    [red] => array[16,10,21]
)
```

Maybe I have to ask user to provide excluded attributes for it to work? Ex: Exclude [xs,xl,xs,10,20,30] or by the attribute group [attribute_pa_size,attribute_height] (see original implode)

*Original array before implode:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [pid] => 100
            [variations] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [attribute_pa_color] => blue
                                    [attribute_pa_size] => m
                                    [attribute_height] => 10
                                )

                            [image_id] => 13
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [attribute_pa_color] => blue
                                    [attribute_pa_size] => m
                                    [attribute_height] => 20
                                )

                            [image_id] => 13
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [attribute_pa_color] => blue
                                    [attribute_pa_size] => m
                                    [attribute_height] => 30
                                )

                            [image_id] => 13
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [attribute_pa_color] => blue
                                    [attribute_pa_size] => xl
                                    [attribute_height] => 10
                                )

                            [image_id] => 18
                        )

                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [attribute_pa_color] => blue
                                    [attribute_pa_size] => xl
                                    [attribute_height] => 20
                                )

                            [image_id] => 18
                        )

                    [5] => Array
                        (
                            [attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [attribute_pa_color] => blue
                                    [attribute_pa_size] => xl
                                    [attribute_height] => 30
                                )

                            [image_id] => 18
                        )

                    [6] => Array
                        (
                            [attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [attribute_pa_color] => blue
                                    [attribute_pa_size] => xs
                                    [attribute_height] => 10
                                )

                            [image_id] => 12
                        )

                    [7] => Array
                        (
                            [attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [attribute_pa_color] => blue
                                    [attribute_pa_size] => xs
                                    [attribute_height] => 20
                                )

                            [image_id] => 12
                        )

                    [8] => Array
                        (
                            [attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [attribute_pa_color] => blue
                                    [attribute_pa_size] => xs
                                    [attribute_height] => 30
                                )

                            [image_id] => 12
                        )

                    [9] => Array
                        (
                            [attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [attribute_pa_color] => green
                                    [attribute_pa_size] => m
                                    [attribute_height] => 10
                                )

                            [image_id] => 17
                        )

                    [10] => Array
                        (
                            [attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [attribute_pa_color] => green
                                    [attribute_pa_size] => m
                                    [attribute_height] => 20
                                )

                            [image_id] => 17
                        )

                    [11] => Array
                        (
                            [attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [attribute_pa_color] => green
                                    [attribute_pa_size] => m
                                    [attribute_height] => 30
                                )

                            [image_id] => 17
                        )

                    [12] => Array
                        (
                            [attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [attribute_pa_color] => green
                                    [attribute_pa_size] => xl
                                    [attribute_height] => 10
                                )

                            [image_id] => 15
                        )

                    [13] => Array
                        (
                            [attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [attribute_pa_color] => green
                                    [attribute_pa_size] => xl
                                    [attribute_height] => 20
                                )

                            [image_id] => 15
                        )

                    [14] => Array
                        (
                            [attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [attribute_pa_color] => green
                                    [attribute_pa_size] => xl
                                    [attribute_height] => 30
                                )

                            [image_id] => 15
                        )

                    [15] => Array
                        (
                            [attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [attribute_pa_color] => green
                                    [attribute_pa_size] => xs
                                    [attribute_height] => 10
                                )

                            [image_id] => 11
                        )

                    [16] => Array
                        (
                            [attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [attribute_pa_color] => green
                                    [attribute_pa_size] => xs
                                    [attribute_height] => 20
                                )

                            [image_id] => 11
                        )

                    [17] => Array
                        (
                            [attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [attribute_pa_color] => green
                                    [attribute_pa_size] => xs
                                    [attribute_height] => 30
                                )

                            [image_id] => 11
                        )

                    [18] => Array
                        (
                            [attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [attribute_pa_color] => red
                                    [attribute_pa_size] => m
                                    [attribute_height] => 10
                                )

                            [image_id] => 16
                        )

                    [19] => Array
                        (
                            [attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [attribute_pa_color] => red
                                    [attribute_pa_size] => m
                                    [attribute_height] => 20
                                )

                            [image_id] => 16
                        )

                    [20] => Array
                        (
                            [attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [attribute_pa_color] => red
                                    [attribute_pa_size] => m
                                    [attribute_height] => 30
                                )

                            [image_id] => 16
                        )

                    [21] => Array
                        (
                            [attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [attribute_pa_color] => red
                                    [attribute_pa_size] => xl
                                    [attribute_height] => 10
                                )

                            [image_id] => 10
                        )

                    [22] => Array
                        (
                            [attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [attribute_pa_color] => red
                                    [attribute_pa_size] => xl
                                    [attribute_height] => 20
                                )

                            [image_id] => 10
                        )

                    [23] => Array
                        (
                            [attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [attribute_pa_color] => red
                                    [attribute_pa_size] => xl
                                    [attribute_height] => 30
                                )

                            [image_id] => 10
                        )

                    [24] => Array
                        (
                            [attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [attribute_pa_color] => red
                                    [attribute_pa_size] => xs
                                    [attribute_height] => 10
                                )

                            [image_id] => 21
                        )

                    [25] => Array
                        (
                            [attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [attribute_pa_color] => red
                                    [attribute_pa_size] => xs
                                    [attribute_height] => 20
                                )

                            [image_id] => 21
                        )

                    [26] => Array
                        (
                            [attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [attribute_pa_color] => red
                                    [attribute_pa_size] => xs
                                    [attribute_height] => 30
                                )

                            [image_id] => 21
                        )

                )

        )
)
```

Thanks

Comment: All the attributes appear 9 times. None of them is most common.

Comment: true. I have to request to target an attribute.